# Term with this type

Tags: haskell

I would like construct term with type

`((((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> t1) -> t2) -> t1`

But I dont know how start it. I know what I must do if I have something like
`(t1->t2)->t1->t2`.
But in this situation  I have only one argument!  How can this be solved?

Comment: what have you got so far? perhaps you could pass a function as an argument. have you got haskell installed? it is helpful to play around in ghci.

Answer (score 3):

leftaroundabout [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33137456/1477667) the general outlines of what you need to do, but as Ørjan Johansen [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33137340/term-with-this-type#comment54087087_33137456) they missed a key idea that comes in at the very end. I figured I'd expand on Ørjan's comment by adding type signatures from leftaroundabout's development.

```
\(a :: (((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> t1) -> t2) -> a $
  \(b :: (t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> b $
    \(c :: t1) -> a (\ _ -> c)
```

The magic here is that once we need to produce a `t2`, we have a `t1` we can use to provide an argument to `a` to get that `t2`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in a chain `((... -> x) -> y) -> z`, you flip back and forth between covariant and contravariant. What this means: you need to define a `... -> z` function. What you can *use* in this function is a `... -> y`. To actually do anything with that function, you must again supply a `... -> x`.

Applied to your task:

- You must define `((((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> t1) -> t2) -> t2`.
- You can use `(((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> t1) -> t2`.
- You must supply `((t1 -> t2) -> t1) -> t1`
- You can use `(t1 -> t2) -> t1`.
- You must supply `t1 -> t2`.

If `t1` and `t2` are really unconstrained type variables, this isn't possible, but I suppose the signature you posted is a bit simplified. Perhaps it's obvious how to define the innermost function, and then the rest is easy too.

Comment: Ah but there *is* an answer. (I cheated with Lambdabot's `@djinn` command.) You missed the next obvious step: "You can use `t1`". Once you have that you can start plugging that into the others. Doing that gave me the same answer djinn did: `\a -> a (\ b -> b (\ c -> a (\ _ -> c)))
`.